# Replicate the behavior of -r option before applying filters

Tags: ffmpeg

When converting the framerate of a video, ffmpeg offers multiple options

one options is `-r`:

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo.mp4 -r 10 my10fpsvideo.mp4
```

another option is using filters:

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo.mp4 -filter_complex [0]fps=fps=10[s0] -map [s0] my10fpsvideo.mp4
```

Using the second option I can apply further filters on the changed fps stream, like selecting a start frame number for exemple `select=gte(n,42)`

Both these solutions don't return the same frames from the original video:

```
-r 10 return the frame indexes  0,1,2,4,7,9,12...
-filter_complex returns indexes     1,3,6,8,11...
```

As you can see `-r` somehow shift the output video by 2 frames and doesn't return the same frames as `-complex_filter`

My problem is I need to apply that start frame number filters, but I also need to extract the exact frames from the original video as `-r` would do

For exemple: If I convert to 10 fps and want to start at frame index `3` I should receive frames `4,7,9,12...`, the frame I would have gotten if had changed framerate using `-r` and skipped the result's first 2 frame

I am constrained to the exact frames returned by `-r` by legacy data that relies on these specific frames to be returned. I am also constrained by the fact that input can be VFR and I can't precompute what frames I need to extract for a given framerate.

Right now the only solution I've found is to read the entire video and discard all frame up to that frame number, which is long and cost a lot of resources.

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do ?

Comment: Did you just delete an earlier instance of this Q that I answered?

Comment: @gyan Yes, another user pointed out that this was out of topic on stack overflow and needed to be deleted and reposted on video.stackexchange, which is what I did

Comment: a) you aren't obliged to follow that, b) see your deleted questions and refer to my answer for a solution

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `-r` and `-filter_complex` together. They are different ways of changing the frame rate. `-r` is an input or output option. `-filter_complex` is a `filtergraph` option. They have different logic and behavior.
You may try this command:

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo.mp4 -vf “select=‘gte(n,3)’,setpts=N/10/TB” my10fpsvideo.mp4
```

This will skip the first three frames and then change the frame rate to 10 using the `setpts` filter. It should give you the same result as `-r 10` and then skipping two frames. However, I do not know if it works for variable frame rate input. You have to test it yourself.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your answer, unfortunately, it doesn work even in CFR, if I understood correctly, to get X fps and start at frame F, I should enter the command:
ffmpeg -i myvideo.mp4 -vf “select=‘gte(n,<F+1>)’,setpts=N/<X>/TB” my10fpsvideo.mp4

When I try your exact example for frame 2 at 10 fps, I get the frames: [3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,7]